# ezplot in MATLAB, how to plot using a function handle?

Tags: matlab, plot, function-handle

I've tried this:

```
linefunca = @(xa,ya) aa*xa + ba*ya + ca;

figure(1)
imshow(Pica);
hold on;
ezplot(linefunca,[1,1072,1,712]);
```

But I'm returned with this error:

```
 In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

Error in ezplotfeval/applyfun (line 80)
       z(i) = feval(f,x(i),y(i));

Error in ezplotfeval (line 65)
    z = applyfun(x,y);

Error in ezplot>ezimplicit (line 257)
u = ezplotfeval(f, X, Y);

Error in ezplot (line 153)
            hp = ezimplicit(cax, f{1}, vars, labels, args{:});

Error in ps3 (line 313)
ezplot(linefunca,[1,1072,1,712]);
```

`aa`,`ba`,`ca` are all known values (column vectors). The x and y limits are the size of the image that I'm working with. I'm trying to plot a set of epipolar lines. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

```
lt = length(aa);
linefunca = @(x,y,t) aa.*x(t) + ba.*y(t) + ca(t);
figure(1)
imshow(Pica);
hold on;

for t=1:lt
    ezplot(@(x,y,t) linefunca(x,y,t),[1,lt]);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `ezplot` can not plot a series of lines like `plot`. A way to work around this would be to add a parameter `k` to the anonymous function, which is used to select the current line. You can then go through all lines in a for loop and plot them one-by-one.

Further: as it is stated on the [`ezplot` help page](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html), you have to use the array functions `.*`, `./` and `.^` , so `ezplot` can use vectors to evaluate the function.

```
N = 5;
aa = rand(N,1); ba = rand(N,1); ca = rand(N,1);
linefunca = @(xa,ya,k) aa(k).*xa + ba(k).*ya + ca(k);

hold on
for k=1:N
    ezplot(@(x,y)linefunca(x,y,k),[-5,5,-5,5]);
end
hold off
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but this gives me the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you added the `.*`? If I copy the example code from my answer it works fine.

Comment: I didn't copy it exactly as you wrote it; I tried it in my code. See my edit.

Comment: Try changing the part in the for loop to `ezplot(@(x,y) linefunca(x,y,t),[1,lt]);`, as the `ezplot` function should see `t` as  constant value and not as variable to `linefunca`.

Comment: Ah just found sth else: you wrote `x(t)` and `y(t)` instead of `aa(t)` and `ba(t)`. Please change this, then it should work.